# Create backbone kind of events system like events object

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I want to create backbone kind of event system like following

```
events: {
    'click #btn': 'functionName'
}
```

I know one of the way is [here](http://blog.joecorcoran.co.uk/2013/06/01/building-a-minimal-javascript-event-system/) but this is more like pub/sub. I want to the above kind of events system. I am googling this but cannot find appropriate article on it which could help me build this system. How can I build above events system for my project?

Comment: I don't understand what is wrong with the linked article or just using Backbone.Events.

Comment: Are you trying to create the event system as a separate library, outside of Backbone? The backbone source code is very well documented and you could probably get what you need by referencing [backbone.view](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-125)